# Understanding C++ code with 'new' and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, argument-passing, assignment-operator

This might be simple but I am getting trouble understanding it.

An excerpt of the code I am trying to understand:

```
SomeStruct ***namestruct = new SomeStruct **[intVariable];
           //Three level pointer and... two level pointer?
                                 //or product and pointer?

for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++)
  namestruct[i] = new SomeStruct *[2]; //creates the same structure time 2?

for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++) {  // just initialization of a
  namestruct[i][0] = NULL;            // matrix like structure?
  namestruct[i][1] = NULL;
}
```

The code works, but I need to understand why the programmer did what it's done.

How can I assign the address from another instance of the structure passed as an address through a function? Example:

```
void function(SomeStruct **othername);

int main()
{
  SomeStruct *othername;
  function(&othername);
  return 0;
}

void function(SomeStruct **othername)
{
  SomeStruct ***namestruct = new SomeStruct **[intVariable];
  for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++)
    namestruct[i] = new SomeStruct *[2];

  for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++) {  
    namestruct[i][0] = NULL;
    namestruct[i][1] = NULL;
  }

  // This is what I want to do
  ...
  namestruct[x][0] = &othername[i]; // Error cannot convert SomeStruct**
                                      // to SomeStruct* in assignment
  ...
}
```

Thanks for you help! The questions are in the code itself and the method to assign the address of the `otherstruct` to `namestruct`.

Comment: There's no `new` operator in C. This is C++.

Comment: There's no such thing as "C code with `new`" (unless someone is playing some really bad joke on you and `#define`d the `new` keyword as an evil macro). This is C++.

Comment: Oh, I will update the title and tags! BTW, thanks already! I was supposed to be ANSI-C, first misunderstanding already.

Comment: if you are new to c++ and confused by `new` you should read a book or a tutorial. this is not the right place to ask these questions. come back when you have something more specific.

Comment: `otherstruct` is not defined in your code.

Comment: I know and would love to read a book on C++. I understand that `new` creates the structure on the heap, but maybe I am missing details. I have this project in hand and I'm trying to figure out this. Thanks anyway @KarolyHorvath! Maybe someone else might have some time to help.

Comment: @MooseBoys sorry a typo.

Comment: if it's on the heap, it has to necessary add one level of indirection (a pointer to ....). if you are familiar with `malloc`, it's the same principle. does that solve the mistery? ;)

Comment: "I have this project in hand and I'm trying to figure out this" -- I'm so so so so so sorry for you. Really. I'll pray for your soul.

Comment: @Jefffrey Thank man! Just to make one thing clear... Isn't this place a community where we can ask questions with code we are struggling with? I would understand and feel bad is someone who is intending to make a profit comes and still your ideas or knowledge for free (and we might have awful lots situations like that), but I am just a student (look the profile) trying to learn from more knowledgeable and experienced people. It is hard to get in touch sometimes with the people who really knows... Sorry again if I bothered people. And Lots of thanks to those who take their time to answer.

Comment: BTW, I really hope in the near future I will be able to give more answers as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make the assumption that this is in fact your question:

> How can I assign the address from another instance of the structure
>   passed as an address through a function?

Short answer:

```
namestruct[x][0] = othername[i]; //if othername is SomeStruct**
```

Long answer:

```
SomeStruct ***namestruct = new SomeStruct **[intVariable];
// namestruct is a three level pointer, that means you will need three levels
// of dereferencing to get to an actual value
// the use of [] notation is the same as a pointer, except you can allocate space
// in memory. You may recognize the difference between 
// char *someString; //uninitialized, _points_ to 1 available bytes
// char someString[12]; //uninitialized _points_ to 12 available bytes
// now, in order to get a value from either of these _pointers_ you use [] 
// as a way of dereferencing

// the way array dereferencing works is simply that you multiply the sizeof(obj)
// with the index, and offset your pointer that many bytes
// such that someString[3] == *(someString + sizeof(char)*3)

// this means, namestruct is now an 'array' i.e it has memory allocated 
// for intVariable instances, those locations are typed to be SomeStruct **


for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++)
    namestruct[i] = new SomeStruct *[2]; // since we've learned that * and [] is 
    // almost the same thing, the type SomeStruct *[2] is the same that we expected here
    // which was SomeStruct **
    // namestruct[i][x] will be typed to SomeStruct *, because we dereference two layers
    // from the original three with the use of the array indexer

for(int i=0; i < intVariable; i++) {  // this is initializing the two pointers generated
    namestruct[i][0] = NULL;          // in the loop above with new SomeStruct *[2];
    namestruct[i][1] = NULL;          // to 0 or NULL
}

// You can assign any SomeStruct* to a namestruct[x][y] deref
// because the types will match.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You know, my compiler played a trick on me... I tried what you said before and kept highlighting the error, then after your answer I tried compiling it again and voila! Sometimes Eclipse Nsight have some glitches... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following illustrates the state of your pointer arrays prior to the problematic assignment:

```
[SomeStruct***("namestruct")]
    |
    V
    [0:SomeStruct**][1:SomeStruct**][2:SomeStruct**][ ...
           |               |               |
           |               |               V
           |               |               [0:SomeStruct*][1:SomeStruct*]
           |               |                   (NULL)         (NULL)
           |               V
           |               [0:SomeStruct*][1:SomeStruct*]
           |                   (NULL)         (NULL)
           V
           [0:SomeStruct*][1:SomeStruct*]
               (NULL)         (NULL)

[SomeStruct**("othername, function scope")]
     |
     V
     [0:SomeStruct*("othername, main scope")]
```

At this point, if you want to assign the `SomeStruct*` at one of the leaf nodes to point to the same `SomeStruct` as `othername` in the `main` scope, you would do `namestruct[x][0] = *othername`. Note that you can eliminate the extra level of pointer if this is, in fact, your goal:

```
SomeStruct *othername;
function(othername);
//...
void function(SomeStruct *othername)
{
   //...
   namestruct[x][0] = othername;
```

Comment: that's a lot of effort for such ... code. +1 for pretty graphs (haven't verified them, but I take it if you spend the time, you know what it does :/)

Comment: @MooseBoys fantastic effort. Same to AlexanderBrevig.